# The compact-open topology on the Pontryagin dual is the weakest topology that make all Fourier transforms continuous

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group with a non-trivial Haar measure $\mu$. Show that the topology (compact-open topology) of $\widehat{G}$ is the weakest topology such that $\widehat{f}$ is continuous for every $f\in L^1(G)$.
Here $\widehat{G}$ is the Pontryagin dual of $G$, that is the space of all continuous homomorphisms $\xi:G\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $\widehat{f}:\widehat{G}\to\mathbb{C}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ defined by the formula:
  $$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_G f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi(x)}\,d\mu(x).$$
I don't know how to get started, thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know if this can help, but Rudin proves in his book [_Fourier Analysis on Groups_](https://books.google.ch/books?id=k3RNtFSBH8gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=rudin+fourier&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), p. 10, that the weak topology for $\widehat G$ is the compact-open topology.

Comment: @Watson Thanks, it it of great help.