# Do compact convergence topology and w*-topology coincide on the Pontryagin dual group of a LCA group.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Given a locally compact group $G$, consider its Pontryagin dual $G^{'}$. Do  compact convergence topology and weak*-topology on $G^{'}$ coincide?. When we talk about weak*-topology on $G^{'}$, it means to view $G^{'}$ to be in the space of $L^{\infty}(G)$ with the relative weak*-topology.

My way is to prove that the identity on $G^{'}$ is a homeomorphism. But I cannot prove the continuity from the weak*-topology to the compact convergence topology. I think $G^{'}$ is not closed in the weak*-topology. Is it right?

I also want to ask that is $G^{'}$ always 1st countable or even metrizable?

Thank you!

Comment: The most general form of this is that the compact open (compact convergence) topology and weak star topology are equivalent on positive definite functions. The general proof is very laborious, but it is simplified when considering the dual group since you have a nice algebraic structure. I proved the equivalence in my master's project. If you want to see the proof, I can send you the relevant portion. You can find the proof of the general result (concerning positive definite functions) in Folland in his chapter on positive definite functions, but the proof is very taxing and built upon lemmas.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671983/the-compact-open-topology-on-the-pontryagin-dual-is-the-weakest-topology-that-ma